# Arcular triangle inequality

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, elementary-proofs

Is it true that if inside a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) $S$, with vertices $a$ and $b$, we take two circular arcs, one from $a$ to $c$ and the other from $c$ to $b$, then the sum of the lengths of these two arcs will be always at most the length of the arc from $a$ to $b$ on the boundary of the original circular segment?

Note that I do not require the two smaller arcs to have the same center, but I want both to be strictly contained in $S$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the arcs bend the other way, then "yes";
otherwise there is an obvious counterexample.

Note that the statement holds if $c\in [a,b]$.
Moreover, if the arcs $ac$ and $bc$ are tangent to the arc $ab$ at $a$ and $b$ respectively, then equality holds.
Furthermore, note that we can assume that $ac$ and $bc$ are tangent to $ab$.

On the following diagram, if arcs look tangent, then they are.

[image]

Observe that
$|ab|=|ac|+|cx|+|xb|\geqslant |ac|+|cb|$, where $|{*}{*}|$ denotes the length of the arc.

Comment: I assume you mean that first you assume that the arcs are tangent, then claim that equality holds if $c\in [a,b]$.
Does your solution also work if one or both of the arcs $ac$ and $cb$ bend the other way?

Comment: @domotorp I will fix it, thank you. If arcs can bend the other way, then the statement does not hold. Take $c$ on the arc $ab$ closer to $a$; choose arcs $ac$ that are tangent to the line segment $ab$ and let $bc$ be subarc of $ab$.

Comment: Indeed, thank you! Let me confess something. I knew a proof for the case when the arcs bend as in your solution, but it was a tedious computation, see page 17 here:
https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02187821 Your solution is much nicer.